# Spring amqp recovery mechanism

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have read the doc which says

```
Spring AMQP now uses the 4.0.x version of amqp-client, which has auto recovery enabled by default.
```

Is spring amqp's auto recovery mechanism exactly same as the native recovery mechanism provided by rabbitmq amqp-client or it has its own stuff beyond what is provided by rabbitmq amqp-client? If so what are the additional features spring amqp provides in terms of auto recovery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring AMQP has had its own recovery mechanism for over a decade - predating the auto recovery provided by the client by several years.

It's not really additional, it provides the same functionality, but in a different manner; the two are incompatible and spring-amqp effectively disables the built-in mechanism.

Comment: But it seems to be contradictory to what doc says which says spring amqp uses amqp client and has auto recovery enabled by default. Aslo the framework is completely compatible with auto recovery being enabled (https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#auto-recovery). Sounds like the built-in mechanism is enabled by default and spring uses that. Unless you are referring to a different thing?

Comment: That documentation is out of date; I will fix it; we tried for years to make them work together, but it was like whack-a-mole; each time we fixed some small corner case, another one popped up. Ultimately, we effectively disable the amqp-client mechanism by immediately closing any auto-recovered connection. So that Spring's built-in mechanism can take over.